# Security when changing views (routing) in single page application

Tags: security, authentication, backbone.js, single-page-application

I'm developing a single page applicaton in `Backbone.js`, with a `PHP` backend. I've never developed SPA's before, so I'm wondering how to properly secure it. It's relatively straight forward to secure requests, by using csrf tokens and doing token based authentication.

**But how do we secure the frontend views? Is this even nessesary?**

I haven't found any litterature on the subject, other than suggested cookie based authentication. [Wunderlist](http://wunderlist.com) uses a very simple "LOGGEDIN=true" cookie, but if I delete this, I'm still able to navigate around the app.

As I see it, we have the following options:

- Ask the server if we're logged in or not when the main view changes, by sending a request to e.g. `/auth`. This would work, but it seems like a waste of resources.
- Use a simple cookie to check if we're allowed to change the view. Do not care about the actual validity of the cookie. Authenticate properly when user requests resources.

I'm beginning to think the second option is enough, as a change to a view usually also involves a request to some kind of resource, but then again, if the cookie is not validated, what use does it have?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create static login.html.
2. Redirect user to this page in case he do not have a valid cookie (GET).
3. End XHR with 401 status code in case user do not have a valid cookie.
4. Redirect to the SPA only after login was successful.
5. Setup the client - redirect to the login page in case user got 401 error code.

Client-side example:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr) {
  if (xhr.status === 401) {
    // redirect to login.html
  }
});
```